# Reassigning local commits to a new branch in git

Tags: git

Basically I made a mistake.

Locally I was developing on `master` and was `committing` and `merging` away as `master` was moving forward; when the time came to `push`, I realized I wanted to have the commits on a branch and not on master just yet.

I can't stash since it's already committed, and the merging seems to further complicate things.

How do I move my "local" commits to a new branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git rebase` and/or `git cherry-pick`. See their manual pages for more info.